# Align Grid in RelativeLayout

Tags: java, android-studio, android-relativelayout

I am a novice in android studio and after trying different layouts with not really satisifying success, I am now back to Relative Layout.
I want to have grid of buttons and the alignments work okay when the buttons are aligned to the end of start of a button the same size, but sometimes I want two smaller buttons underneath a bigger button, but since I can only align the left smaller button with the start of the bigger button and the right smaller button with the end of the end of the bigger button, the space between the smaller buttons is not aligned and causes all kind of problems.
How do I align those two buttons in the middle?

Here is my manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="26dp"
        android:layout_height="34dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/enterYouText"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/enterYouText"
        android:background="@null"
        android:minWidth="0dp"
        android:minHeight="0dp"
        android:text="SPEAK" />


<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/throat"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/secondPage"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/head"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/kopf"
        android:adjustViewBounds="false"
        android:backgroundTint="#FAF6F6"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@mipmap/picture" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/head"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/secondPage"
        android:layout_alignStart="@id/button"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/xy"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
        android:adjustViewBounds="false"
        android:backgroundTint="#FAF6F6"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@mipmap/picture" />



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/secondPage"

        android:layout_width="225dp"
        android:layout_height="23dp"

        android:layout_below="@id/button"
        android:layout_alignStart="@id/button"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/enterYouText"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:background="@drawable/buttonsmall"
        android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
        android:shadowDx="0"
        android:shadowDy="0"
        android:shadowRadius="5"
        android:text="Second Page"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, what you have to do to `align center`(horizontally and vertically which means middle of whole screen).

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
```

alternatively,

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

This way you can put buttons on center. Suppose, you put a button(called `A`) on center. Now, you wanna put another button beside that button. Than you have to write

```
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/A"
```

above code in button `B`. If you want to put another button on left of button `A`. Then, try

```
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/A"
```